# Firebase cloud function security using triggers without resulting in infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement some security checks to my cloud function triggers, but as I discovered my current set up results in an infinite loop from the onCreate and onDelete triggers when doc is not valid. How would I go about using onCreate and onDelete triggers for security without resulting in an infinite loop or is there another way that can achieve this without using firestore security rules?

```
  export const createEventTrigger = functions.firestore.document("events/{id}").onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    const event = snapshot.data() as Event;

    const isValid = await isEventDocumentCreateValid(context, event);

    if (!isValid) {
      // Delete the document if it’s invalid
      console.log(
        `Deleting invalid document for user ${getInvokerUid(context)}`
      );
      await snapshot.ref.delete();
    }
  });
```

```
  export const deleteEventTrigger = functions.firestore.document("events/{id}").onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {
    // Contents of the document as a JavaScript object
    const event = snapshot.data() as Event;

    const isValid = await isEventDocumentDeleteValid(context, event);

    if (!isValid) {
      // Add back the document if it’s invalid
      console.log(
        `Adding back doc after invalid document delete for user ${getInvokerUid(
          context
        )}`
      );
      await snapshot.ref.set(event);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you share what the `isEventDocumentCreateValid` and `isEventDocumentDeleteValid` functions are?

Comment: If your function executes, it has nothing to do with the security rules that came before it.  If you think there is a correlation, your question should explain should explain that, showing the rules, and how it's not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson the rules are working as expected. The question is asking more so how to structure the triggers so that onCreate and onDelete don't result in an infinite loop after checking the conditions.

Comment: Please edit the question to show all of the relevant code.  We can't see `isEventDocumentCreateValid`.  Also we need to know how you are triggering these functions and how you observe that they are executing.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to duplicate the behavior you observe.